# I am interested on the functions $g:ℂ×ℂ→ℂ$ of the form $g(x+iy,x-iy)=g(z,\overline{z})$

Tags: complex-analysis, reference-request

I am interested on the functions $g:ℂ×ℂ→ℂ$ of the form $$g(x+iy,x-iy)=g(z,\overline{z})$$ My question is about **requesting** some references dealing with this type of functions.

Comment: The "...of the form" condition you specify is not a condition on $g$ at all; presumably you're asking about functions $f:\mathbf{C}\to\mathbf{C}$ such that $f(z)=g(z,\bar{z})$ for some function $g:\mathbf{C} \times \mathbf{C} \to \mathbf{C}$, and the condition you wish to impose is that $f$ or $g$ is holomorphic? (If that's right, froggie's answer seems likely to address what your question.)

Comment: @user86418: Yes, you are right, I am asking just for a reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on what class of maps $g$ you are wanting to consider, the answer to this question will vary greatly. I'm going to assume that since you've tagged this question as complex analysis, that you are assuming $g$ to be holomorphic.

First note that any holomorphic function $g\colon \mathbb{C}\times \mathbb{C}\to \mathbb{C}$ is real analytic, and so is the composition $z\mapsto g(z,\overline{z})$. Thus the class of maps you are interested in is contained in the class of real analytic maps $\mathbb{C}\to \mathbb{C}$.

On the other hand, suppose that $f\colon \mathbb{C}\to \mathbb{C}$ is real analytic. Then it can be written as a convergent power series $$f(x,y) = \sum_{n,m\geq 0}a_{nm}x^ny^m,$$ where $a_{nm}\in\mathbb{C}$. But note that you can rewrite this as a power series $$f(x,y) = \sum_{n,m\geq 0} a_{nm}\left(\frac{z+\overline{z}}{2}\right)^n\left(\frac{z-\overline{z}}{2i}\right)^m = \sum_{k,l\geq 0}b_{kl}z^k\overline{z}^l =g(z,\overline{z}),$$ where $g(z,w) = \sum_{k,l\geq 0}b_{kl}z^kw^l\colon \mathbb{C}\times\mathbb{C}\to \mathbb{C}$ is holomorphic.

So, unless I screwed this up (you should check, for instance, that the power series for $g$ converges!), the class of functions you want information about is just the class of real analytic functions $\mathbb{C}\to \mathbb{C}$.

For a reference on real analytic functions, see for instance the book *A Primer of Real Analytic Functions* by Krantz and Parks. Maybe other people have other suggestions.